# Bash script does not end Java process clicking on the "X"

Tags: java, bash

Can someone explain to me why this is the case. Let's say I have a simple java program that loops forever until I kill the process.

If I make a shell script like this.

```
#!/bin/bash

# clears the terminal
clear

# runs the java executable
java -jar java_program.jar

# prevents the terminal from  closing
$SHELL
```

The shell script runs the program and if I use hotkey CTRL + C it ends the java process exactly how I want it. But when I use the "X" in the top right corner the java process does not end. Why does it do this how do I solve this issue?

I know the java process does not end because if I look in task manager the process is still running.

I am using windows 10.

[image: task]

Comment: Hi, Bash on windows  ? do you use cygwin on the embedded ubuntu version ?

Comment: @hgregoire No I use git bash

Comment: Apparently, the window closing doesn't send the sigterm signal.. I don't know how to correctly start the java program

Comment: @hgregoire The java program can be any java executable. The program just has to have an infinite loop to keep it running. Is it possible to use a trap and redirect the X to ctrl C?

Comment: I don't know on Windows , it's works fine on Linux and mac

Comment: @hgregoire Ok, so this must be a Windows-related issue then.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have git bash installed, but the behaviour you perceive comes from the terminal emulator that is used around git bash. It is not the windows native terminal emulator (and running cmd), it is not the cygwin terminal emuator.

Since you have it installed figure out the software emulating the terminal and see how that treats the processes when you close the terminal window. Maybe it is configurable.